# Nim: How can I improve concurrent async response time and quota to match cpythons asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, request, nim-lang

For an upcoming project this year, I wanted to look into some languages that I haven't really used yet, but that repeatedly catch my interest. Nim is one of them .

I wrote the following code to make async requests:

```
import asyncdispatch, httpclient, strformat, times, strutils

let urls = newHttpClient().getContent("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tobealive/b2c6e348dac6b3f0ffa150639ad94211/raw/31524a7aac392402e354bced9307debd5315f0e8/100-popular-urls.txt").splitLines()[0..99]

proc getHttpResp(client: AsyncHttpClient, url: string): Future[string] {.async.} =
  try:
    result = await client.getContent(url)
    echo &"{url} - response length: {len(result)}"
  except Exception as e:
    echo &"Error: {url} - {e.name}"

proc requestUrls(urls: seq[string]) {.async.} =
  let start = epochTime()
  echo "Starting requests..."

  var futures: seq[Future[string]]
  for url in urls:
    var client = newAsyncHttpClient()
    futures.add client.getHttpResp(&"http://www.{url}")
  for i in 0..urls.len-1:
    discard await futures[i]

  echo &"Requested {len(urls)} websites in {epochTime() - start}."

waitFor requestUrls(urls)
```

**Results doing some loops:**

```
Iterations: 10. Total errors: 94.
Average time to request 100 websites: 9.98s.
```

The finished application will only request from a single ressource. So for example, when requesting Google search queries (for simplicity just the numbers from 1 to 100), the result look like:

```
Iterations: 1. Total errors: 0.
Time to request 100 google searches: 3.75s.
```

---

Compared to Python, there are still significant differences:

```py
import asyncio, time, requests
from aiohttp import ClientSession

urls = requests.get(
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tobealive/b2c6e348dac6b3f0ffa150639ad94211/raw/31524a7aac392402e354bced9307debd5315f0e8/100-popular-urls.txt"
).text.split('\n')


async def getHttpResp(url: str, session: ClientSession):
  try:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
      result = await resp.read()
      print(f"{url} - response length: {len(result)}")
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {url} - {e.__class__}")


async def requestUrls(urls: list[str]):
  start = time.time()
  print("Starting requests...")

  async with ClientSession() as session:
    await asyncio.gather(*[getHttpResp(f"http://www.{url}", session) for url in urls])

  print(f"Requested {len(urls)} websites in {time.time() - start}.")


# await requestUrls(urls) # jupyter
asyncio.run(requestUrls(urls))
```

**Results:**

```
Iterations: 10. Total errors: 10.
Average time to request 100 websites: 7.92s.
```

When requesting only google search queries:

```
Iterations: 1. Total errors: 0.
Time to request 100 google searches: 1.38s.
```

(I'm not big into python, but when using it, it's often impressive what it's C libraries deliver.)

---

The difference in response time remains when **just getting the response status code**.

---

To improve the Nim code, I thought it might be worth trying to add channels and multiple clients (this is from a still very limited point of view on my second day of programming in Nim + generally not having a lot of experience with concurrent requests). But I haven't really figured out how to get it to work.

Doing a lot of request to the same endpoint in the nim example (e.g. when doing the google searches) it also may result in a `Too Many Requests` error if this amount of Google searches are performed repeatedly. In python this doesn't seem to be the case.

**So it would be great if you could share your approach on what can be done to improve the response quota and request time!**

If anyone wants a repo for cloning and tinkering, this one contains the example with the loop:
https://github.com/tobealive/nim-async-requests-example

Comment: Regarding the idea of implementing parallelism, I had a chance to have a look at the book "Nim in Action". It says that async await is strictly concurrent and that it is likely that a future version of Nim will include an async await that is parallel.

Comment: One thing to note is that the User-Agent is different for both http clients and therefore the responses and behavior you'll get from different websites will be different.  This may affect response types (200 vs 4xx/5xx errors) as well as response content, which would ultimately affect the overall timing and performance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remember how Nims async works, and can unfortunately see no real issue in your code. Compiling with -d:release seems to make not a big difference. One idea is the timeout, which may be different for Python. From https://nim-lang.org/docs/httpclient.html#timeouts we learn that there is no timeout for async, so a very slow page may keep the connection open for a long time. Maybe Python does a time-out? I was not able to test the Python module, aiohttp is missing on my box. Below is a test of mine, not that different from yours. I made main() not async, by using waitFor all(f). Sorry that I could not really help you, maybe you should really try the chronos variant.

```
# nim r -d:ssl -d:release t.nim
import std/[asyncdispatch, httpclient, strutils, strformat, times]

const
  UrlSource = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tobealive/" & 
    "b2c6e348dac6b3f0ffa150639ad94211/raw/31524a7aac392402e354bced9307debd5315f0e8/" &
    "100-popular-urls.txt"

proc getHttpResp(client: AsyncHttpClient, url: string): Future[string] {.async.} =
  try:
    result = await client.getContent(url)
    echo &"{url} - response length: {len(result)}"
  except Exception as e:
    echo &"Error: {url} - {e.name}"

proc main =
  let start = epochTime()
  echo "Starting requests..."
  var urls = newHttpClient().getContent(UrlSource).splitLines
  if urls.len > 100: # in case that there are more than 100, clamp it 
    urls.setLen(100)
  # urls.setLen(3) # for fast tests with only a few urls
  var f: seq[Future[string]]
  for url in urls:
    let client = newAsyncHttpClient()
    f.add(client.getHttpResp(&"http://www.{url}"))
  let res: seq[string] = waitFor all(f)
  for x in res:
    echo x.len
  echo fmt"Requested {len(urls)} websites in {epochTime() - start:.2f} seconds."

main()
```

Testing with an extended version of the above program, I get the feeling that the total transfer rate is just limited to a few MB/s, and my idea about timeouts was very wrong. I did some Google search about the topic, was not able to find much useful info. As you wrote in your initial post already, Nim's async from standard library is not parallel, but it is (theoretical) possible to use it with multiple threads. When I have more free time, I may do a test with Chronos.

```
# nim r -d:ssl -d:release t.nim
import std/[asyncdispatch, httpclient, strutils, strformat, times]

const
  UrlSource = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tobealive/" & 
    "b2c6e348dac6b3f0ffa150639ad94211/raw/31524a7aac392402e354bced9307debd5315f0e8/" &
    "100-popular-urls.txt"

proc getHttpResp(client: AsyncHttpClient, url: string): Future[string] {.async.} =
  let start = epochTime()
  try:
    result = await client.getContent(url)
    stdout.write &"{url} - response length: {len(result)}"
  except Exception as e:
    stdout.write &"Error: {url} - {e.name}"
  echo fmt" --- Request took {epochTime() - start:.2f} seconds."

proc main =
  var transferred: int = 0
  let start = epochTime()
  echo "Starting requests..."
  var urls = newHttpClient().getContent(UrlSource).splitLines
  if urls.len > 100: # in case that there are more than 100, clamp it 
    urls.setLen(100)
  #urls.setLen(3) # for fast tests with only a few urls
  var f: seq[Future[string]]
  for url in urls:
    let client = newAsyncHttpClient()
    f.add(client.getHttpResp(&"http://www.{url}"))
  let res: seq[string] = waitFor all(f)
  for x in res:
    transferred += x.len
  echo fmt"Sum of transferred data: {transferred} bytes. ({transferred.float / (1024 * 1024).float / (epochTime() - start):.2f} MBytes/s)"
  echo fmt"Requested {len(urls)} websites in {epochTime() - start:.2f} seconds."

main()
```

References:

https://xmonader.github.io/nimdays/day04_asynclinkschecker.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I worked quite a bit with your input, but not with Chronos yet. Adding a timeout for the initial response helped a bit to remove occasional outliers. Otherwise, the initial response is immediate. The problem lies in the processing time of items after the response. If I would add a timeout for this, we gather a lot of timed-out items so I leave it out. The amount of transferred data is similar to Python and Haskell. I only have Haskell locally at the moment, but it performs the best currently. For Nim, we definetely should check out Chronos to get more improvement.

Comment: It would get a little verbose updating the question, and the initial problem still remains. So I just updated the repo for now.

Comment: Having tried choros: requests to a single source keep up with the speed of Python and Haskell! However, when requesting different sources, there is a load up of connection or redirection errors (among some other errors). I didn't found out how to iron them out and will stop trying now with Nim. As a conclusion, I think it's fine to use Nim if one only wants to query a single source concurrently.